# How exactly does hotreload work in React?

Tags: reactjs

I don't really understand the magic of hotreload. I have some lines of code that should only ever run once otherwise it will throw an error. Example

```js
ModuleManager.registerModule('abc', Module);
```

If this code is run again, it will throw an error because someone already registered module with name `abc`.

Now I go about my business and make a change to the UI causing a hot reload. No issues. Another one, all good. And another one, uh oh, I get an error from my `ModuleManager` that `abc` has already been registered. Why did it occur this time?

When hotreload occurs, does it basically recreate the production file (webpack or whatever) and run all code again?